# What is the event when the user leaves the site in signalr?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

What the user is leaving the event site in order to change their status from online to offline and send a message to clients states that he left the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tie into the disconnected event.

SO in your hub add the method:

```
public override Task OnDisconnected()
{
    // The Context.ConnectionId is the identity of the disconnected client
    return Clients.All.userOffline(/* Something here to identify the user */);
}
```